# Bootstrap: Responsively Centering Buttons within Div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am playing around with some code using bootstrap.  I'm trying to make my bottom navbar with the buttons centered.  The options I have found online involve setting a specific width, which messed up my responsive design. What is the best way to center the content?

Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Logo</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/products">Products</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/about-us">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
      <div class="jumbotron text-center under">
    <div class="transparent vert-center">
    <h1 id="heading-title">Website Heading</h1>
      <p id="heading-desc">Information about the website!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center outline">
                <h2>Text</h2>
                <p>More text describing the heading!</p>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf size"></span>

            </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center outline">
                <h2>Text</h2>
                <p>More text describing the heading!</p>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hourglass size"></span>

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center outline">
                <h2>Text</h2>
                <p>More text describing the heading!</p>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus size"></span>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-bottom">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                <h3 class="footer-heading">Footer Title</h3>
                <button type="button" class="btn-success btn-format">Click</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn-success btn-format">Click</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center outline">
                <h3 class="footer-heading">Footer Title</h3>
                <button type="button" class="btn-success btn-format">Click</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn-success btn-format">Click</button>

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                <h3 class="footer-heading">Footer Title</h3>
                <button type="button" class="btn-success btn-format">Click</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn-success btn-format">Click</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Top nav syling */
.navbar-default{
    background-color: rgb(54, 135, 2);
    font-size: 120%;
}

/*Main display styling */

.jumbotron{
    height: 400px;
    background: url("../images/bg.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    width: 96%;
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(79, 201, 2);
    border-top: 5px solid rgb(79, 201,2);
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

/*Navbar font coloring */
.nav.navbar-nav li a {
    color: white;
}

/* Centers content vertically */
.vert-center{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

/*Styles partially transparent background within jumbotron class */
.transparent{
    background: rgba(190, 200, 216,.5);
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-left: 4px solid rgb(79, 201, 2);
    border-right: 4px solid rgb(79, 201, 2);
    width: 60%;
}

/*Padding around desc within jumbotron */
#heading-desc {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

/*Padding around title within jumbotron */
#heading-title{
    padding-top: 15px;
}

/* Bootstrap menu created using bootstrapdesigntools.com */
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: rgba(54, 135, 2, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(47, 196, 116, 1) 0%, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(47, 196, 116, 1) 0%, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 100%);
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(90, 224, 4, 1);
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(68, 168, 5, 1);
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #44a805;
}

/*Styling of icons */
.size{
    font-size: 60px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

/*Outline surrounding three columns including icons */
.outline {
    border-left: 2px solid rgb(79, 201, 2);
    border-right: 2px solid rgb(79, 201, 2);
}
.navbar-bottom {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(201, 199, 199, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(201, 199, 199, 1) 100%);
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 2px;
    margin-top: 90px;
}
.btn-format {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    left: 50%;
    height: 9%;
}
.horizontal-center{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100px;
}
}
.footer-heading {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
footer-title-pad {
    padding-top: 2px;
}

/* Unsure: Guessing- targeting id custom-bootstrap-menu class navbar-default, and class navbar-brand.
What does the space between ".navbar-default and .navbar represent instead of linking them as with
"custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar"*/
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
/* sets font-color for the menubar and brand */
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
/*Unsure: Guessing- targeting id custom-bootstrap menu and class navbar-default */
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
/*sets font size for font within navbar... brand too? */
    font-size: 15px;
/*Possibly a fallback for browsers that do not support gradients*/
    background-color: rgba(47, 196, 116, 1);
/*Gradient for main coloring of menubar */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 0%, rgba(47, 196, 116, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 0%, rgba(47, 196, 116, 1) 100%);
/*Sets border width and rounds edges slightly */
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
/*Unsure:  Guessing-Targets #custom-bootstrap-menu id, navbar-default class and .navb-nav class
and all links within lists */
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
/*Sets text color of white to list items with links inside? */
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
/*Really confused what this does for the menubar.  Fully transparent white background-color? */
    background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0);
}
/*When two tags are included like this does the rule simply apply to both?*/

/*Unsure: guessing-targets id custom-bootstra-menu and class navbar-nav's liste
items with links when the user hovers? */
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
/*Targets the same as above, but upon focus.  I have some experience with focus from javascript but
could use a more clear understanding.  My rough understanding is it is while an element is in use */
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
/*Sets color of text when hover/focus occurs? */
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
/*Green background color- unsure what it's doing exactly*/
    background-color: rgba(68, 229, 74, 1);
}
/*Unsure: guessing- Targets id custom-bootstrap-menu, class navbar-default and all
links within an element with the class active? */
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
/*Unsure: guessing-Targets same as previous and styles the link color and background color of something on hover on hover */
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
/*Unsure: guessing-Targets same as above and styles link color and background color of something on focus */
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
/*Font color of white */
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
/*Background color- not sure for what.  Fallback for older browsers potentially */
    background-color: rgba(66, 165, 3, 1);
/*Gradient- not sure what it's styling */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 0%, rgba(66, 165, 3, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 0%, rgba(66, 165, 3, 1) 100%);
}
/*Unsure: Guessing-targets id custom-bootstrap-menu class navbar-default and navbar-toggle
does navbar-toggle change the display once the screen has been resized? */
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
/*border color */
    border-color: #42a503;
}
/*Unsure: Guessing-targets id custom-bootstrap-menu class navbar-default and navbar-toggle on focus and hover */
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
/*Sets the background color- not sure on what */
    background-color: #42a503;
}
/*targets id custom-bootstrap-menu class navbar-default and navbar-toggle and icon icon-bar.
Possibly styles something on screen resize?*/
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
/*setting the background color- not sure of what*/
    background-color: #42a503;
}
/*Targets id custum-boostrap-menu class navbar default and navbar-toggle on hover/focus and class icon bar
does this target the color of the background once the screen is resized and the user hovers/focuses*/
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
/*background color- not sure of what */
    background-color: #2fc474;
}
.btn-center{

}
```

Ignore CSS comments

Comment: We'll need to see your code in order to help

Comment: Wow.  can't believe I just did that

Comment: Up now! My mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since they are block elements, you can center them with `margin:auto;`

```
.navbar-bottom button {
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Marked your answer as correct because it allowed me to keep my block display; even though the other comment worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just update you `button` CSS with following code

```
.btn-format {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    /*left: 50%;*/
    height: 9%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Is there a way to mark your answer correct aswell?

Comment: You can refer following link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235